# Adjust Image if page break occurs in mpdf library

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, simple-html-dom, mpdf

I am generating pdf from html source using mpdf library in php and everything seems working perfect.

Now I have an issue with the images. Suppose before page end I'm inserting an image but image is big so that it doesn't fit at the bottom of first page and goes to second page. Now I have a long white space at the end of first page because image moved to second page.

Now I want is "if next item to insert in pdf is an image then calculate the remaining size of pdf page if it is less than Image size then adjust the image size so that image can be fit in the pdf page instead of moving to next page" how can i do this here?

Please check the issue image :

[image]

If any one has other solution please help me to sort out.

Here's My sample code

```
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';  //import html dom and mpdf library
include 'PDFScript/MPDF/mpdf.php';

$mpdf = new mPDF('','','','',15,15,30,15,8,8);  //create mpdf object
$html = new simple_html_dom();  //create html dom object
$html = file_get_html("htmlsource.html");   //htmlsource.html is a webpage can contain any html data
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);  //write html source to pdf
$mpdf->Output();  //generate pdf
```

Answer (score 3):

I got a solution from mpdf forum itself. If Anyone also has the same problem enclose every image in your html inside table as table has a autosize feature in mpdf library.

For more information please check [here](http://www.mpdf1.com/forum/discussion/1774/adjust-image-if-pagebreak)