# How can I center image in mpdf?

Tags: php, center, mpdf

I would like to centre image in `mpdf` (version 6>).

This is my (shortened) html output that I send to mpdf. The `displayed` class does not help.

```
<style>
IMG.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }
</style>

<img style="max-height:600px" class="displayed" src="/images/size_original/m_princezna_1.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a `text-align: center` property on a parent HTML element of the image, eg.:

```
body { text-align: center }
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried the solution of Finwe but that moved the image to next page. So did a workaround with a combination of solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24992651/905323) of Ram Guru99 and there :

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <img src="<?php echo $imagepath ;?>"/>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to center image in the page.

```
<p style="text-align:center;">
<img src="imageurl.png"/>
</p>
```