# How to make image position center in div mpdf

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, mpdf

I want to make a pdf report with mpdf. I want to add user's logo in pdf page.

I want to ask how to make image in center div even the image size is different ?

Here's two different image that I used as an example

```
https://picsum.photos/200/300 //picture 1

https://picsum.photos/200 // picture 2
```

Right now, the image position is not center div. If image is landscape, the image is not center in div.

Here's two different image size

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['format' => [145 , 210]]);
$logo = $this->input->get('logo');
$html = $this->load->view('pages/pdfreport',array("logo" => $logo),true);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    
$mpdf->Image($qrimage, 37, 80, 70, 70, 'jpg', '', true);
$mpdf->Output('report.pdf', 'I');
```

Here's the pdf view

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .frame{
            background-color:black;
            margin-top:-20px;
            height:125px;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
            display: flex;
        }
        .logo {
            max-width: 125px;
            max-height: 125px;
            border-style: none;
            margin: auto;
            display: table-cell;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
        <div class="frame">
            <img class="logo" id="logo" src="<?= $logo; ?>">
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Do you know to make image center in div even if image is portrait or landscape ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I center image in mpdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851940/how-can-i-center-image-in-mpdf)

Comment: Hi @Finwe, I've got some tips from that, thank you